# Aligning columns in a string made up of spaces in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to append a string made up of spaces in JTextArea.
Everything is fine with the code and logic but the output is not the way i want it. 
The output I get is like this,

Actual output

[image: Actual output]

Desired output

[image: Desired output]

It's a prescription and the '0---0---0' string is related to dosage instruction which I want to look like this,

My code is,

```
medicinename_str = medicinepanel.getComboBox().getEditor().getItem().toString();
        strength_str = strength.getText();
        if(morning.isSelected()){
           timings_str = timings_str + "1-----" ;
        }else{
           timings_str = timings_str + "0-----" ;
        }
        if(afternoon.isSelected()){
            timings_str = timings_str + "1-----" ;
        }else{
           timings_str = timings_str + "0-----" ;
        }
        if(night.isSelected()){
            timings_str = timings_str + "1" ;
        }else{
           timings_str = timings_str + "0" ;
        }
        quantity_str = quantity.getText();
        medicinename_str = "Tab. "+medicinename_str;
        int spaces = spacelength - medicinename_str.length();//spacelength is initialized to 40 in the constructor of the JPanel the JTextArea is added in.
        System.out.println("spaces ="+spaces);
        String spacestring = " ";
        for(int i = 1; i<spaces; i++){
           spacestring = spacestring + " ";
        }
        medicinename_str = medicinename_str+spacestring;
        MainFrame.getPrescriptionArea().append(medicinename_str);
        System.out.println("Medicine strlength "+medicinename_str.length());
        MainFrame.getPrescriptionArea().append(timings_str+"\n");

        timings_str = "";
```

Comment: yes a mistake.. just edited.. please checkout and help... thanks

Comment: This is because the font is not fixed width. use some monospace font

Comment: Are you sure if i use a monospace font the problem will be solved?

Comment: Then logic?
I subtracted the medicine + dosage string from a constant width 40 to generate the length of string with spaces.

Comment: Yes the code executes after each medicine selected...

Comment: just print your output in console, copy paste in the an editor and change font to consolas or courier new. See if it correctly indented or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening due to the font being non-monospace.

For the same text:

```
Tab.Amusulpride          0-----0-----0
Tab.Abilify              0-----0-----0
```

With Arial (non-monospace)

[image]

With Courier New (monospace)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Will try it and accept this answer as a satisfying one.

Comment: Cheers mate .. . :)